# object blink or disappear and appear when click on screen - vuforia augmented reality

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, touchscreen, android-augmented-reality

when displaying object using vuforia ground plane stage object is displaying but when I click (touch) on screen object is blinking or moving or it is disappearing and appearing on some new place. Basically what my requirement is if I touch on screen object should not move , it should be on same place or it should not just disappear and appear.

steps : 1) I integrated Vuforia 
2) deleted main camera and added ARcamera next added Ground plane stage and ground plane finder.
3) Added a cube as child to Ground plane stage.

Comment: are you trying this for the first time ?

Comment: yes , I mean I tried sample AR apps all are working fine but only when I touched on screen object will disappear and appear. its not duplicate object instantiate problem I unchecked duplicate stage